# sprite images using <img>

Tags: html, css, sprite, css-sprites

I have an image which is made up of 2 images, a sprite.

What I'm looking to do, is have this as a sprite, so when I hover over it, the bottom part of the image is visible.

I know I can do this using `background-position` in CSS, but this is an `<img>` tag in the HTML.

How could I do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how this can be achieved with CSS transitions:

http://jsfiddle.net/NGWuZ/

markup:

```
<div class="container">
    <img src="my_image_url">
</div>​
```

css:

```
.container{
    height: 175px;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;  
}
.container img{
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    transition: top 2s;
    -moz-transition: top 2s; /* Firefox 4 */
    -webkit-transition: top 2s; /* Safari and Chrome */
    -o-transition: top 2s; /* Opera */
}

.container img:hover{
   top: 175px;
}
```

Comment: ...somebody said "animated", right?
(should also work without the transition;)

Answer (score 1):

Use a containing div where the CSS propery `overflow` is set to `hidden`.  You can then use JavaScript to resize the containing div as necessary.

Comment: Why use JavaScript? Just change the height of the `div` when it's in a hover state: `div:hover {height: 100px;}` or something.

Answer (score 0):

In your situation, I would add a container to the image which is now absolutely positioned and when hovering the container, I would move the image position.

HTML:

```
<div class="myContainer">
   <img src="mySpriteImage" alt="" width="50" height="50" />
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.myContainer {
    position:relative;
    overflow:hidden;
    width:50px;
    height:25px;
}
.myContainer img {
    position:absolute;
    top:0;left:0;
}
.myContainer:hover img {
    top:auto;bottom:0;
}
```